# Handling multiple variable results

Tags: php

So here is my case:
I have three functions performing some chemical reactions(synthesis1(), synthesis2() & synthesis3() ).
All of these functions will give an answer or a fail in the results.
They were originally separate scripts but are now in a class.
NB: the functions work fine by themselves, even in the class.
Below is my script to instantiate the class and start the functions.

My problem is that since i am running a reaction which fires all the  functions;
i get one 1 correct answer and two fails or three fail at once.

What is the best way to handle the situation.
I want one correct answer and suppress the two fails or just show one fail in case of three fails(all fails). I don't expect three right answers.
P.s. All answers are strings.

```
 <?php
// create an object for class name
 $aaa = new synthesis();
 $abc = new synthesis();
 $abcd = new synthesis();

// call the functions in the class
$synthesis1 = $aaa->synthesis1();
$synthesis2 = $abc->synthesis2();
$synthesis3 = $abcd->synthesis3();

// call the if functions
$searches = array($synthesis1, $synthesis2, $synthesis3);

foreach($searches as $search) {
if ($aaa->synthesis1($search)){
    echo 'Match found: ' . $search;
    break;
}

    elseif ($abc->synthesis2($search)){
            echo 'Match found: ' . $search;
            break;
        }

        elseif ($abcd->synthesis3($search)){
            echo 'Match found: ' . $search;
            break;
        }

        else{ echo"Please try again or try another reaction";}

}
?>
```

Comment: Why are you calling the synthesis functions again in the loop? Don't you just want to check whether `$search` is a success or failure result?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know why you need to instantiate three different objects if you have three individually named methods.

I would think you might want to add a method to your class to simply run all synthesis methods all at once and return the result. So something like:

```
class synthesis {
    protected $synthesis_methods = array(
        'synthesis1',
        'synthesis2',
        'synthesis3',
        // add more methods here if needed
    }
    public function synthesis1() {
        // your method logic here
    }
    public function synthesis2() {
        // your method logic here
    }
    public function synthesis2() {
        // your method logic here
    }
    public function synthesize_all() {
        $result = false;
        $i = 0;
        while(false === $result && $i < count($this->synthesis_methods)) {
            $result = call_user_func(array($this, $this->synthesis_methods[$i]));
            $i++;
        }
        return $result;
    }
}
```

You would then only instantiate a single object.  Usage would be:

```
$synth_obj = new synthesis();
var_dump($synth_obj->synthesize_all());
```

Comment: Great answer. I will try one this way.

Comment: So, my functions return a String or false(null or no reaction) for my answers. Which is good; is there a way to assign the false result a value after the fact? Say if false, return this other value/string instead? Would that mean another function to handle the results?

Comment: @Edwinner The way I wrote that `syntehsize_all()` method is that it would return the first successful function result or `false` if all methods fail. If you want to return something other than false, you can just return some other value instead (i.e. after loop run `if(false === $result) { return null; } else { return $result; }`

Answer (score 0):

An easy way to handle this is to use OR logic:

```
if($aaa->synthesis1($search) or $abc->synthesis2($search) or $abcd->synthesis3($search))
{
    echo "Match Found: $search";
    break;
}
else
{
    echo "Please try again or try another reaction.";
}
```

Comment: This solves the one answer part, but it does not do anything about the fail answers. Still a good answer though! Can you edit it more?